# how to use tokens with sklearn in LDA

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, lda, countvectorizer

i have a list of tokenized documents,containing both unigrams, bi-grams and i would like to perform sklearn lda on it.i have tried the following code:

```
my_data =[['low-rank matrix','detection method','problem finding'],['probabilistic inference','problem finding','statistical learning','solution' ],['detection method','probabilistic inference','population','language']...]
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=2, max_features=n_features,
                                stop_words='english')
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(mydata)

lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=3, max_iter=5,random_state=10)
```

but when i print the output i get something like this:

```
topic 0:
detection,finding, solution ,method,problem 
topic 1:
language, statistical , problem, learning,finding 
and so on..
```

bigrams are broken and are separated from one another.i have 10,000 documents and  already tokenize them, also the method for finding the bigram is not nltk based so i already did this. 
is there any method to improve this  without changing the input? 
 i am very new in using sklearn so  apologies in advance if i am making some obvious mistake.

Answer (score 0):

[CountVectorizer has a `ngram_range` param](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) which will be used for deciding if the vocabulary will contain uniqrams, or bigrams or trigrams etc:-

> **ngram_range** : tuple (min_n, max_n)
>
> The lower and upper boundary of the
>   range of n-values for different n-grams to be extracted. All values of
>   n such that min_n <= n <= max_n will be used.

For example:

- `ngram_range=(1,1)` => Will include only unigrams
- `ngram_range=(1,2)` => Will include unigrams and bigrams
- `ngram_range=(2,2)` => Will include only bigrams
- and so on...

You have not defined that, so default `ngram_range=(1,1)` and hence only unigrams are used here.

```
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=2, 
                                max_features=n_features,
                                stop_words='english',
                                ngram_range = (2,2))  # You need this
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(my_data)
```

---

Secondly, you say that you have `already tokenize` the data and show the lists of list (`my_data`) in your code. That doesnt work with `CountVectorizer`.  For that, you need to pass a simple list of strings and `CountVectorizer` will automatically apply tokenizing on them. So you will need to pass on your own preprocessing steps to that. See other params `'preprocessor'`, `'tokenizer'` and `'analyzer'` in the linked documentation.

Comment: this ngram_range is defining the bigrams,but using this  dont get the already defined tokens.it gave me some think like (solution solution).

Comment: @ameera For that, you will need to give me the input data you used in `CountVectorizer` and how you tokenized them.  As I have already said in my answer that your current `lists of list` dont work.

Comment: thank you for replying. i just read about "lists of list" thing. there is no way to use list of lists with countvectorizer?

Comment: No. As I said above, `CountVectorizer`  expects an iterable (a list, or file reader) of strings, not list of lists. By the way, if you have list of list how are you able to use the code successfully, and get the unigrams as answer. What input are you using?

Comment: My input is not based on English. so if provide you the input-data you cant understand them.it is same like the one defined in my_data.i have already tokenized docs,consist of different length of terms(unigrams,bigrams and trigrams) i wanted to perform lda on it using sklearn.

Comment: It doesnt matter. I dont need to understand the input. I need to know the exact code you have. Showing different code in the question and using a different one yourself is not gonna help you.

Comment: the code is not much different from this except input.                                 docs = get_lda_input_from_corpus_folder(CORPUS_PATH)
  vectorizer=CountVectorizer(min_df=1,
            stop_words=load_stopwords(STOP_WORDS_FILES))
  tf = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)
  lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=n_topics, n_iter=lda_n_iter,
                    random_state=lda_random_state)